# mysql Duplicate error handling

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use PHP to enter data from a form. When I try to enter duplicate data a bad message pops like

Something went wrong with this:

```
INSERT INTO customer VALUES('jamie9422','Jamie Lannister','sept of baelor','jamie@cersei.com',9422222222,0) Duplicate entry 'jamie9422' for key 'PRIMARY' "
```

Instead, I want to display a clean error message. How can I do that. Here's my code I've written so far...

```
<?php
     include_once "dbConnect.php";
     $connection=connectDB();

    if(!$connection)
    {
        die("Couldn't connect to the database");
    }
    $tempEmail = strpos("{$_POST["email"]}","@");

    $customer_id=substr("{$_POST["email"]}",0,$tempEmail).substr("{$_POST["phone"]}",0,4);

    //$result=mysqli_query($connection,"select customer_id from customer where customer_id='$customer_id' ");
    //echo "customer_id is".$result;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID='$customer_id'";

    $customer_idcip = $customer_id-1;
    echo $customer_idcip;

    if ( mysql_query($query)) {
        echo "It seems that user is already registered";
    } else {
        $command = "INSERT INTO customer VALUES('{$customer_id}','{$_POST["name"]}','{$_POST["address"]}','{$_POST["email"]}',{$_POST["phone"]},0)";

        $res =$connection->query($command);
        if(!$res){
            die("<br>Something went wrong with this:{$command}\n{$connection->error}");
        }

        echo "Welcome ".$_POST["name"]." \nCongratulations on successful Registration. Refill your Wallet here";

        //$cutomerRetrival = mysql_query("select  from customer where customer_id='$customer_id'");
        echo "<br>Please note your customer ID :".$customer_id;                 
    }       
    /*if($result)
    {
        echo "Query Fired";
        $dupentry = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($dupentry==1)
        {
            echo "You are already Registered";
            exit;
        }
    }*/
?>
```

Comment: You have already have a user called `jamie9422` in your database table.

Comment: make check for duplicate keys before inserting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [Try Catch](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) instead.

```
try{
   $res =$connection->query($command);
}catch(Exception $e){
  die( "Write your error appropriate message here"); 
}
```

Comment: '$e->getMessage()'  will give exact error that happened in try block. Exception handling is more important in this case.

Comment: someone did't like my answer. why? :(

Answer (score 0):

The [error code (number) is 1022](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_dup_key).
You can e.g. define a constant for that (so that somebody else in x months has a chance to understand the code) like

```
define('ER_DUP_KEY', 1022);
```

and then do something like

```
if(!$res){
  if ( <error code>==ER_DUP_KEY ) {
    handleDuplicateEntryError();
  }
  else {
    die("<br>Something went wrong with this:{$command}\n{$connection->error}");
  }
}
```

since I don't know how `$res =$connection->query($command);` works (and what `$connection` is I can't tell you exactly how to implement `<error code>==ER_DUP_KEY`, could be by using [mysql_errno](http://docs.php.net/mysql_errno).
But it seems to be somehow intermingled with `mysql_query($query)`, i.e. the old, deprecated mysql_* extension and some custom class. You might want to fix that first.... ;-)
see http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't check for existing record properly

Change

```
if (mysql_query($query)) {
    echo "It seems that user is already registered";
}
```

to

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    echo "It seems that user is already registered";
}
```

Also, PLEASE do not use $_POST variables without escaping them first, use something like mysql_real_escape_string() to escape each variable passed from the user, otherwise your website will be hacked really fast with SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Make some update into your and then try to get error message 'customer already registered.'

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER_ID='$customer_id'";
$res= mysql_query($query);
$customer_count = mysql_num_rows($res);

$customer_idcip = $customer_id-1;
echo $customer_idcip;

if ( $customer_count > 0 ) {
echo "It seems that user is already registered";
} else {
  ...................................
```

Comment: how is that different from my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. 
Actually  I was using mysqli API in my connectDB.php file..
Hence I needed to call functions on mysqli.
Instead I was calling mysql. i.e I was creating a new connection, thus the query wasn't getting fired at all.
Changed to mysqli->query($result) that is object oriented style
and it worked fine....